# Where can I see a summary of the comments I have made, like the question and answer summaries on my profile?

Tags: support, comments

I tried searching many times in my profile, help center, here and Google, but I seem to be missing something.

Is there a way to see a Comments summary of my comments just like 'Answers' and 'Questions' summaries?

I comment on questions here and there and sometimes forget about the comments / threads, thus unable to find the questions when there is no new activity or simply get lost in the notifications.

Comment: This should be what you are looking for: https://askubuntu.com/users/1040551/grumpyburger?tab=activity&sort=comments

Comment: Oh wow, I feel stupid now. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have hidden it well, but there is such a [page](https://askubuntu.com/users/current/?tab=activity&sort=comments)

[image: all actions section in profile]

[image: comments section in all actions]